# Match everything but \(\d\)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
fadjfl (10) fdaf
fadjfl dafhaj (10)
fadjfl dafhaj 34 (10)
fadjfl dafhaj 34 dafads      (10)
fadjfl dafhaj 34 dafa(ds) ((  (10)
fadjfl 
fadjfl dafhaj 
fadjfl dafhaj 34 
fadjfl dafhaj 34 dafads      
fadjfl dafhaj 34 dafa(ds) ((
```

I need regex that will select everything but **(10)**

Comment: What tool are you using? (It especially matters in this case)

Comment: I need it in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always specify an implementation (PHP, Javascript, .NET, etc.) if you're not asking a theoretical question about regular expressions, which would probably belong in cs.stackexchange.com anyway.

To start you off though, if you only want the string before the `\(\d+\)`, then:

```
(.*?)(?:\(\d+\)|$)
```

If you want everything, then that's not really possible if you can have multiple parenthesized digits. It's possible for a finite number, *e.g.* 3:

```
(.*?)(?:\(\d+\)|$)(.*?)(?:\(\d+\)|$)(.*?)(?:\(\d+\)|$)
```

Unless you're using .NET:

```
((.*?)(?:\(\d+\)|$))*
```

after which you can cycle through the `GroupCollection`.

Comment: +1 A universal approach that will work with most engines, though it does require extra code to extract the match.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to match from the beginning of each line up until the `"(10)"` at then end of each line, and assuming you are using a tool capable of [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can use something like this:

```
.*?(?=\(10\)|$)
```

It will match everything up until the following characters are `"(10)"` (but will not include `"(10)"`) or the end of the line is reached. It's important to use the non-greedy quantifier (`.*?`) in this case, otherwise the regex will match the entire line every time.

If you mean that you want to match the entire document except for `"(10)"` then you can easily use any kind of string replace function, replacing `"(10)"` with `""`.

Comment: Tried this one but it doesn't work for examples fasjfl and below

Answer (score 1):

A regex that `match()`es something *not* would be very comlicated. Instead, just remove the parts you do not want:

```
myStr.replace(/\(\d+\)/, "")
myStr.split(/\(\d+\)/)
```